# No Firebase App ’[DEFAULT]’ has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() Error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have encountered an error while creating an app stating that there is no firebase app. I checked on what the issue might be from my code and went to the internet for solutions to solve the problem but the solution provided does not solve my issue. The solution states that I should check whether I have properly initialized my app in the main.dart file(which I did) but I still get the error when I try to register a user. Any idea on how to sort this out?
Here is my main.dart code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/responsive_layout_screen.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:insta_leafy/screens/login_screen.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'insta_leafy',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCGEnIwaIMg4LSwDu_WRP2UxFviPZXGktY",
      appId: "1:1076571433842:android:cf2a80ac3ca34bccf60beb",
      messagingSenderId: "1076571433842",
      projectId: "leafy-clone",
      storageBucket: "leafy-clone.appspot.com",
    ),
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Instagram Clone',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
      ),
      // home: const ResponsiveLayout(
      //   mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
      //   webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
      // ),
      home: SignUpScreen(),
    );
  }
}
 "leafy-clone.appspot.com",
```

here is the error:

```
E/flutter (19978): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
E/flutter (19978): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:193:5)
E/flutter (19978): #1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:56:41)
E/flutter (19978): #2      FirebaseAuth.instance (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:38:47)
E/flutter (19978): #3      new AuthMethods (package:insta_leafy/resources/auth_methods.dart:7:43)
E/flutter (19978): #4      _SignUpScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:insta_leafy/screens/signup_screen.dart:121:38)
E/flutter (19978): #5      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
E/flutter (19978): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
E/flutter (19978): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
E/flutter (19978): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
E/flutter (19978): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:7)
E/flutter (19978): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
E/flutter (19978): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter (19978): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter (19978): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
E/flutter (19978): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter (19978): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter (19978): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:488:19)
E/flutter (19978): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:468:22)
E/flutter (19978): #18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:439:11)
E/flutter (19978): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
E/flutter (19978): #20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
E/flutter (19978): #21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
E/flutter (19978): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
E/flutter (19978): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
E/flutter (19978): #24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
E/flutter (19978): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
E/flutter (19978):
```

I went to the main.dart file to ensure that I had initialized the app, to which I did initialize but the problem still persisted, I also ensure that i had installed all the relevant packages needed for my app but Firebase was still not able to sign up a user

UPDATE:
I added the details from the json file to the options but the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

change your Firebase initialize from this

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'insta_leafy',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      //added the details
    ),
  );
```

to this

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

Comment: I have tried your method but its unable to identify DefaultFirebaseOptions.

Comment: are you sure that you have connected your app to firebase properly? you can try to delete firebase_options.dart file and connect your app again with firebase CLI , and on which you are working i mean Windows or MAC?

Comment: I am working on windows. Let me try your recommendation again and see if it picks up

Answer (score 0):

First try this like Raj's answer,

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'insta_leafy',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      //added the details
    ),
  );
```

If it hasn't worked, try this; it will work,

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'your-app',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'your api key',
        appId: 'appId',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        projectId: 'your-app',
      ));
```

You can find all this details (apiKey, appId...) in `google-services.json` file.

Comment: I found the details and added them but the error is still there.

Comment: it shows same error?

Comment: Yes it shows the same error.